# paddleocr erro:invalid ppem value

Tags: python, fonts, truetype, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

[image]
plesae help me

```
font_path = 'D:/download/PaddleOCR-release-2.7/doc/fonts/simfang.ttf' # PaddleOCR下提供字体包
image = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
im_show = draw_structure_result(image, result,font_path=font_path)
```

how to solve this bug

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your traceback error as text and not as an image.